# How to use flexbox for text components in react native? Horizontal wrap, Vertical increment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to produce an effect in react native that given a certain array of text, it wraps and at the same time it increases the size vertically, creating a new line for the next words:

```
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 0.3,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  wordsContent: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  txt: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width
  }
});

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const words = ['asdfasdf', 'asdf asdf', 'qwerqwer', 'qwer qwer', 'qwerwwe', 's332', '123123', 'sdfasdf'];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.wordsContent}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Words:
          </Text>
          {
            words.map((w, i) =>
              <Text style={styles.txt} key={i}>
                {w}
              </Text>
            )
          }
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I would like to keep on adding words to the array, and those words should go to the next line. Notice that the "word" in the array can have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a solution that is not elegant:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  wordsWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  wordsContent: {
    flex: 0.5,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  word: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5
  },
  txt: {
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderColor: 'black',
  }
});

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  getWordsPerColumn() {
    const words = ['asdfasdf', 'asdf asdf', 'qwerqwer', '123321', 'asdfasdf', 'asdf asdf', 'qwerqwer', '123321', 'asdf asdf', 'qwerqwer', '123321', 'asdf asdf', 'qwerqwer', '123321', 'qwerqwer', '123321' ];
    const maxColumns = 5;
    const cells = 4;
    let columns = maxColumns;
    if (words.length <= 4) {
      columns = 1;
    } else if (words.length <= 8) {
      columns = 2;
    } else if (words.length <= 12) {
      columns = 3;
    } else if (words.length <= 16) {
      columns = 4;
    }
    const groups = [];
    let groupNumber = 0;
    let keys = 0;
    for(let i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
      if (!groups[groupNumber]) {
        groups.push([]);
      }
      for(let j = 1; j <= cells; j++) {
        groups[groupNumber].push(
          <Text key={keys} style={styles.word}>
            {
              words[keys]
            }
          </Text>
        );
        keys++;
      }
      groupNumber++;
    }
    return groups;
  }
  render() {
    let key = 0;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.wordsContent}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Words:
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.wordsWrapper}>
          {
            this.getWordsPerColumn().map((column, i) => (
                <View key={key++} style={styles.txt} >
                  {
                    column.map((w, j) => w)
                  }
                </View>
              )
            )
          }
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

For the moment I don't expect to have more than a certain quantity of words... I will probably need a better solution than this in the near future, any cool idea will be welcome.

[image]